# random number based on probability in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I create a random number generator which calculates a random number based on a probability?

For example, I have the following numbers with the probability they will occur starting in cell A1 and B1:

```
100 5%
75  10%
50  42%
30  30%
15  5%
0   8%
```

Thus, the formula would "randomly" return the number "15" 5% of all times.

Comment: Should the probabilities be interpolated? E.g. may the random-number-generator produce value "80"? "80.5"? Integers-only? Maximum/minimum?

Comment: The generator should only produce the integers 0,15,30,50,75,100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slightly less overhead:

Make a reference chart of your values, and a running total of probability:

```
C   D   E
100 5%  0
75  10% 5%
50  42% 15%
30  30% 57%
15  5%  87%
0   8%  92%
```

Then lookup a 0-1 random number on this chart.  `=LOOKUP(RAND(),$E$2:$E$7,$C$2:$C$7)`

I generated 5224 numbers and produced this pivot chart of the results.  Refreshing caused the percentages to waver a bit around the targets, but all attempts looked good.

```
Row Labels  Count   Percentage  Target
       0     421        8.06%      8%
      15     262        5.02%      5%
      30    1608       30.78%     30%
      50    2160       41.35%     42%
      75     490        9.38%     10%
     100     283        5.42%      5%
Grand Total 5224    100.00%
```

Or you could do it with two cells and a long if statement:
`=RAND()`
`=IF(A9<0.05,100,IF(A9<0.15,75,  ... 0))...`

Comment: Note if you try to combine rand into the if statement, you're going to end up with a different probability curve than if you leave them as two separate formulas and only compute RAND once.

Comment: If you have to do this multiple times, it might be worth doing as a macro instead of as a formula.

Comment: This partially works, but out of 100 trials, "0" never gets returned and I do get "#N/A" 5 times.

Comment: I found the problem with the above. Excel states "If the LOOKUP function can not find an exact match, it chooses the largest value in the lookup_range that is less than or equal to the value.". Thus, I believe column E should be "0%, 5%, 15%, 57%, 87%, 92%"

Comment: Or should it be "0%, 6%, 16%, 58%, 88%, 93%"?

Comment: If it's not 0, 5, ...  then it would be 0, 5.0000001 or some such?

Comment: +1 nice answer Denise - FWIW I think that exactly 5% is the most correct

Comment: I agree that exactly 5% is correct.  Rand returns 0<= x < 1, so the rounding skew should work with us there.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality comes as part of the analysis toolkit add in. You can find this in Excel options -> add ins ->  manage add ins.

You want random number generation, and then pick the 'discrete' distribution.  The input into this is the table you provided in your post.

"Discrete
Characterized by a value and the associated probability range. The range
must contain two columns: The left column contains values, and the right
column contains probabilities associated with the value in that row. The sum
of the probabilities must be 1."

jsarma's suggestion is also a good one....

Answer (score 1):

You can use vlookup and randbetween.

You'll want to use randbetween. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/randbetween-HP005209230.aspx

vlookup: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Fill one column with consecutive numbers ranging from 1-100.
Fill another column with 5 100's, 10 75's, 42 50's, etc...

Now...

```
=VLOOKUP(RANDBETWEEN(1,100),A1:B100,2)
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but I tried this and it seems to work.

Comment: This solution does not work for me because the probabilities may change based on another function in another tab